# IIS7.5 - Restricting access to particular sites by client IP

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I know about the [IP4 Address and Domain Restrictions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755206.aspx) feature in IIS7, however this is a Server level setting - there is no way to specify rules for individual sites.

**Is there a way to restrict access by client IP for one Website on a server, but not the others?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP Address and Domain Restrictions is available at the site level too.  That's a good option for simple IP restrictions.

Another option is to use URL Rewrite.  That gives you lots of flexibility, both in what addresses are allowed or denied but also what you do with them when they arrive.

Either solution works.

Comment: I had somehow missed the fact that you could set it for each site.